# How to name these helper functions?

Tags: c#, design-patterns, naming-conventions

```
public class Member
{
    Team team;
    int p;

    public void GoToTeam(Team team)  //  how to name it? MS tells me not to add __
                         //  I want to prevent this be called so easily by mistake
    {
        this.team = team;
        p = team.GetHashCode();     // some setup for team changing, new id, new title, etc
    }
}

public class Team
{
    List<Member> members = new();

    public void AddMember(Member member)    // main func.
           // Team moves people. How about Street? street don't move people
    {
        members.Add(member);
        // and something more, member maps etc
    }
}
```

Member has a GoToTeam function, which cannot work alone, without being called by functions like AddMember.

How to name these helper function in c#, to prevent it to be called alone by mistake?

A good class design would help. Like always Team do action to lower hierachies.
But member is the basic action unit. Do I need a ugly member.AddTeam_wrapper()?

Is there a more straightforward way to do this?
Like __GoToTeam in other languages.

I'm working on composite patterns.
A lot of classes are hierachically structured.
Methods are used to change their relationship.

It's easy to use a half-function by mistake, without a detailed documentation.

> In some languages, you use friend class private, __goto method, to prevent these methods to be used.
> Again, I'm not so good at designing these not so tiny modules, as MS expected :(

When geo-layers, bio-layers, political-layers comes, it's to messy to have one prime rule to identify the **Main function**, which calles other (I call it) **half-functions**.

I want a good naming convention to identify these public methods and public but not standalone methods.

Thank you!

Comment: If you make `GoToTeam` private, then it can only be called from code _within_ the class (like `Member.AddMember`) and not from outside the class (like `Team.AddMember`)

Comment: @Flydog57 Thank you. I correct the name. Member.AddMember_wrapper is only for software "member" users. What troubles me is that GoToTeam must be public but not used alone.

Comment: What is the purpose of `AddMember_wrapper` exactly?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by 'GoToTeam cannot work alone'. As opposed to what?

Comment: The fact that you're not sure what to call your method hints to the fact that the design might not be good. ask yourself
1. Who is responsible for adding a `Member` to a `Team`. Should probably be only one class. I think it should be `Team`.
2. Does a `Member` really need to know which `Team` they are on? You can figure this out in other ways and if you remove the `team` variable in your `Member` class, things become much less complex.

Comment: Are you by chance writing a library for other developers and those other developers should not be able to call the GoToTeam method? If so, you could set the accessibility of the GoToTeam method to `internal`.

Comment: @SaeidAmini It can be directly called by UI, where Team user and Member user have different command entry.

Comment: @SlackGroverglow Thank you. Say objects are geo-structured: Province-City-Street-People. The natural way is People.GotoStreet not Street.MovePeople. And People have change mail address etc, Street change some people list, both function is needed to manage private fields. When I have Team ref ways, and Geo ref ways. It really troubles me to decide which is main function. Maybe I should use __GotoStreet anyway?

Comment: @zhaihouxi you are describing a very common issue when designing an application. Another solution is to create a third class called TeamManager and only allow it to update `Teams` and `Members`. I think all 3 solutions are valid but you know best which works best for your problem

Comment: @SlackGroverglow Yes I'm using a Team ui class to hold all these prime methods for UI. I think a __gotoTeam is all I want, which is not recommended by C#.

Comment: @MySkullCaveIsADarkPlace Great. When I'm coding this library without a document/class diagram, I could use GotoTeam mistake. I think I might stick using __GotoTeam to identify them, as a rookie :(

Answer (score 1):

First of all, if the naming conventions are one of your concerns, you should change `AddMember_wrapper` to `AddMemberWrapper`.

Then, you should consider one of your classes as something like a parent and do any of your actions through it. In this case, you can consider `Team` as a parent and `Member` will be one of its Children([AggregateRoot Pattern](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/DDD_Aggregate.html)). If you want to set a `Team` for a `Member`, you should do it another way around and add the `Member` to a `Team`.

```
public class Team
{
    public List<Member> Members { get; private set; }

    public Team()
    {
        Members = new List<Member>();
    }

    public void ChangeMemberName(int memberId, string newName)
    {
        Member member = Members.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Id == memberId);
        if (member is null)
            throw new ArgumentException("Member not found.");

        member.ChangeName(newName);
    }

    public void AddMember(Member member)
    {
        Members.Add(member);
        // and something more, member maps, etc
    }
}

public class Member
{
    public int Id { get; private set; }
    public string Name { get; private set; }
    // ...

    public Member(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
    }

    public void ChangeName(string newName)
    {
        Name = newName;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. In my project member have team-related private fields, and it has to call a GotoTeam() to change those fields. The public GotoTeam must be called by main function Team.AddMember. When some one writes UI to change team, how do I prevent they use the public GotoTeam?

Comment: If you want to change something in the `Member`, again you should do it through Team(aggregate). Let me change my answer and add more detail

Comment: Thank you. In a simcity, hierachys may be city-district-street-building-people. If I put all method to city manager, is it a god object? I think MS don't recommend me to use __gotoTeam, because there's good mechanics to highlight Main Methods. Friend class private, __goto, these are other language solutions.